# why mongoose queries dos not work when put inside promise function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My code is as shown below:

```
checkAndCreateUser(customer_id, email_id).then(result => {
        console.log("result is " + result);
    });

var checkAndCreateUser = function (custom_id, email) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if ((!custom_id) && (custom_id.trim() == '')) {
            var creatUser = new user();
            // creatUser._id = user_id;
            creatUser.ph_no = ph_no;
            creatUser.email_id = email;
            console.log("fn works");
            user.findOne({
                'email_id': email
            }, function (err, user) {
                console.log("db test");
                if (!user) {
                    creatUser.save(function (err, userInfo) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject("no id found");
                        } else {
                            customer_id = userInfo._id;
                            resolve(customer_id);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    customer_id = user._id;
                    resolve(customer_id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now what happens here is I am not able to successfully run db query. I am able to get **console.log("fn works")** printed , but it does not print **console.log("db test")**. So what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: Mongoose supports promises, you can use them directly instead of embedding request & callback inside an explicit Promise object: `user.findOne({}).then(res => {}).catch(err => {})`

Comment: thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot save your user, besides Mongoose already returned promise, you don't need use callbacks:

```
var checkAndCreateUser = function (custom_id, email) {
    return User.create({ ph_no :ph_no,
                         email_id :email})
    .then(result=>{
        return User.findOne({'email_id': email})
    })
    .then(user=>{
       return user._id;
    })
};
```

As for mistake in your function:

```
...
let user = new User({email_id: email, ph_no: phone});
user.save();//you forgot about this
...
```

You can use save() with callback:

```
user.save((err, result)=>{...});
```

Or with promise:

```
 user.save().then(result=>{...}).catch(err=>{...});
```